# pyrfa DLL load fails

Tags: python, c++, dll, wrapper, reuters

I am trying to use the pyrfa module developed by devcartel.

I have installed the package with the usual method:

```
pip install pyrfa
```

However, running a script that uses the module gives:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed : The specific module cannot be found.
```

The pyrfa module is a wrapper around C++ code based DLLs developed by Reuters. Where do I find the necessary DLLs?

Comment: I don't think this is a valid question here. There are two ways to fix this: The first is to delete it and to file a bug report upstream. The other way is to extract and provide a [mcve], but that means extracting it from the pyrfa sourcecode, but you probably don't want that. That said, there are a bunch of possible reasons why a DLL can't be loaded, including that other DLLs it depends on can't be loaded. Make sure you do some research and rule out the usual suspects.

Answer (score 0):

According to [[GitHub]: devcartel/pyrfa - Installation](https://github.com/devcartel/pyrfa#installation) (**emphasis** is mine):

> **Windows users might need to install [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523) or [(x86)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555)**.

Install the required dependencies for your *Python* architecture (I assume it's *x64* (*AMD64*)), or better: install both of them as it won't hurt (unless you have a *32bit* *Win*), and you should be fine.

Comment: @Svalbard: Did you install the mentioned tools? What's the status now?